# JavaScript debugger shows double colons for object property, Handlebars fails to render

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have this handlebars template:

```
<p class="text-muted">{{ date }} {{ time }} {{ message }}</p>
{{log this}}
```

Rendering it gives me this log in the console:

```
Object
date: "2014-03-22"
message:: "ABC"
time: "01:10:07"
__proto__: Object
```

Note the `message::`, I get double colons in both Firefox and Chrome. I think this is important because this is my rendered output:

```
<p class="text-muted">2014-03-22 01:10:07  </p>
```

Why is `message` missing and what do double colons mean?

Comment: Paste the object creating the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible for a JavaScript object to have a colon (or practically any character) in the name of one of its properties:

```
var a = {"message:": "hello"};
console.log(a);
```

Result:

```
Object {message:: "hello"}
```

It sounds like that's what you have there. Do you perhaps have a stray colon somewhere when you're creating the object?

Comment: That's actually it, weird that I haven't noticed that earlier. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess: is your message actually under the message key? Is it possible that the message value is an empty string, and the key for the line with a message is an empty string too? It would be easier to work this out if you included the message object formatted as JSON.